# List of figures with reference URL

Tags: table-of-contents, urls, links

I want to have a List of Figures, which also contains a reference URL (or the article which I refer to `\cite{}`) for each figure entry. (and if possible the URL should appear in the next line with a little indent for the whole link). For example:

```
2.1 This is a bird .............. 2

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/House_sparrow04.jpg/1280px-House_sparrow04.jpg
```

I already use the package `hyperref`, so I want to keep the backref for the figure (2.1 This is a bird) but I want the URL to be a link.

Example image (if you click the google.com link, then it will still bring you back to the figure instead of to the URL). Even if you click the citation, it will bring you back to the figure:

[image]

Comment: we need more informations how do you plan doing this? i mean in body of docment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution. It allows you to add a link (URL) to the LoF using `\addloflink{<URL>}` which is set using a special LoF-type - `figlink`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addloflink}[1]{% \addloflink{<URL>}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\begingroup\def\protect\@dotsep{10000}% Remove dots in LoF for this entry
    \protect\contentsline{figlink}{\protect\numberline{}\url{#1}}{}{}%
    \endgroup}% Restore dots in LoF for future entries
}
\newcommand{\l@figlink}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Some chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{This is a figure}
  \addloflink{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{This is another figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```